# TypeError while trying to pass Maxcor into L-BFGS-B minimizer

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I got the below error when i tried to specify the maxcor kwarg in L-BFGS-B method. The optimization line is shown below,

```
minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "L-BFGS-B", "bounds": bounds, "maxcor": 190}
BH_result=optimize.basinhopping(obj_Basinhopping, initial_guess, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs, accept_test=mybounds,callback=printx, disp=True)
```

I got the below error,

```
TypeError: minimize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'maxcor'
```

I am very sure i am making a silly mistake here. Anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the options you put in `minimizer_kwargs`, only `method` and `bounds` are actually arguments accepted by [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).  To use the `maxcor` option of the L-BFGS-B method, you'll have to pass that to `minimize` in the `options` argument.  That is:

```
minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "L-BFGS-B",
                    "bounds": bounds,
                    "options": {"maxcor": 190}}
```